# Send coordinates of dynamically drawn box through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, jquery-ajaxq

I am taking an image, saving the first click coordinates, drawing a box based on these then saving the final coordinates. I tried to output the coordinates using `console.log()` and it tracks the right coordinates. The problem is that it does not POST it properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selection = $('<div>').addClass('selection-box');
    var firstClick = true;
    $('#image')
    .data("vals", {xstart: 0, ystart:0})
    .on('dragstart', function(e) { event.preventDefault(); })
    .mousedown(function(e) {
        var xval = Number(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
        var yval = Number(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
        console.log(xval)
        $("#image").data("vals").xstart = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        $("#image").data("vals").ystart = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        $selection.css({
            'top': yval,
            'left': xval,
            'width': 0,
            'height': 0
        });
        $selection.appendTo($('#image'));
        $('#image').mousemove(function(e) {
            var move_x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                move_y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top,
                width  = Math.abs(move_x - xval),
                height = Math.abs(move_y - yval),
                new_x, new_y;
            console.log(xval)

            new_x = (move_x < xval) ? (xval - width) : xval;
            new_y = (move_y < yval) ? (yval - height) : yval;    
            $selection.css({
                'width': width,
                'height': height,
                'top': new_y,
                'left': new_x
            });
        }).mouseup(function(e) {
            xend = Number(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
            yend= Number(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
            //console.log(xval, yval, xend, yend);
            $.ajax({
                 url: '/view/getwords/',
                 type:"POST",
                 data: {
                     xval: xval.toString(),
                     yval: yval.toString(),
                     xend: xend.toString(),
                     yend: yend.toString(),
                 },
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {
                    console.log(xval, yval, xend, yend);
                 },
                 error:function(){
                     alert("Error");
                 }
             });
            $('#image').off('mousemove')
            $selection.remove();
        })
    })
});
```

P.S. This is one of my first questions on StackOverflow so let me know as well if I can ask questions better.

Thank you!

Edit: Here is the snippet of the boxing code I used. http://jsbin.com/ireqix/226/edit?html,js,output
Essentially, I am just trying to POST the coordinates from the snippet above.

Comment: What happens when you `POST`? Have you done `console.log(data)` in the `success` function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Alright, thank you. The mouseup function is inside of the mousedown function. The formatting of the code may have changed through copy pasting. Will fix now.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Nothing happens because it never enters that function

Comment: @KingAlandyDy you're right, now the formatting is corrected. Can you add a full working example of this to the question please. You can use the snippet editor under the `[<>]` button to do this.

Comment: The values seem to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rx6yjgn2/. How have you determined that the POST request is not working? Note that in the fiddle I also remove the `mouseup` event as you're currently stacking them multiple times per `mousedown`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, It just says it is not posting it. I get this error: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/view/getwords/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What do you mean by me stacking them up multiple times per `mousedown`? I did notice that it is saving all my old clicks and trying to post them again and again. That's why for each box I draw, I first receive one error notification, then two, then three, then four.

Comment: That error means the request is being sent with the correct data and it's your server side code that is the problem. The JS is fine.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. You were adding a new `mouseup` event handler every time a `mousedown` happened, but you never removed it. Therefore on the third selection, 3 AJAX requests would be made with the same data. That's *a* problem, but it's not the main problem. As I said above, the problem is in how your server is receiving the data you send. You need to debug that.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to fix it! :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you were right! It was a backend issue. Sorry! Everyone, this code works! You can use it if you have the same problem like me.